# vnc server doesn't start before login

Tags: ssh, login, remote-desktop, vnc

I tried to follow [this guide](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1082848&p=6814386#post6814386) because I need to do exactly te same thing: after restarting a remote pc, I need to access to the login screen with vnc.
Unfortunately, after giving the command `sudo x11vnc -safer -localhost -nopw -once -auth /var/lib/gdm/:0.Xauth -display :0`, the server does not start. I also tried to type `x11vnc -display :1` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43845316/x11vnc-xopendisplay-failed), but it works only if the remote pc is already unlocked, which is exactly what I need to do from remote
I am running *Ubuntu 20.04* 64-bit with Gnome 3.36.8 on both pc; I am using *VNC Viewer* version 6.21.406

Comment: @guiverc question updated; let me know if you need more

Comment: i dont use vnc server. if i were u I would try to create a systemd service file that starts the vnc server on multiuser.target with specified user rights (not as root).